# Transfer items between drop-down lists in different webForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am a not experienced programmer, just a rookie enthusiast.

I have a webForm where I add items to a drop-down list.

There is another webform that contains another drop-down list, I want this second "ddl" to display the items I added to the "first ddl".

After not succeeding with public properties, I tried to get this accomplished in the most straight fashion:

In designer.cs change the first "ddl" from protected global to public.

On the second webForm I wrote:

```
 WebForm3 wf_ConfigurationPage = new WebForm3();
```

And a short function with these lines:

```
ddl_ingenieros.DataSource = wf_ConfigurationPage.ddl_Engineers;
ddl_ingenieros.DataBind();
```

I am calling the function from PageLoad but unfortunately the "ddl" is not showing the items from its "DataSource ddl".

Also, when I switch pages, the items I added to the original "ddl" just disappear.

Can you help me get these 2 issues resolved?

I managed to get something similiar done for a gridview as follows:

On the webform where the original gridview is located:

```
static DataSet DS;
static DataTable tableRequests;

/*  -------------- Public Properties ---------------- */

public DataSet currentList //Allows access from other pages.
{
    get {
        return DS;
    }
}

public DataTable currentTable {
    get {
        return tableRequests;
    }
}
```

On the second webForm I wanted to show the gridview:

```
WebForm1 wf_ActiveReq = new WebForm1();
```

Then a short function that I call from PageLoad, which has these lines:

```
gv_results.DataSource = wf_ActiveReq.currentList;
gv_results.DataBind();
```

---

I was unable to do the same with the ddls because unlike the DataSet and the Data Table, the ddl was created from designer view, when I tried to declared them in the "code behind" of the webForm where the "original" ddl exists I got an error about the object being duplicate, which makes sense.

Thanks for your time

@Erkaner

In first webForm:

```
static List<string> myItems = new List<string>();


    protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["myItems"] != null)
        {
            myItems = (List<string>) Session["myItems"];

        }
        myItems.Add(txt_newAdmin.Text);
        ddl_Engineers.DataSource = myItems;
        ddl_Engineers.DataBind();
        txt_newAdmin.Text = ""; 
    }
```

In second webForm, I wrote a function I call from pageLoad:

```
private void pull_engineersList()
    {

        ddl_ingenieros.DataSource = Session["myItems"];
        ddl_ingenieros.DataBind();            
    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why don't you use database to maintain this kind of work

Comment: Hi - This is a just a prototype I have to present, then just need the values during runtime.

Comment: Moreover page is stateless . You can't expect from a page that he will hold his data after get destroyed.

Comment: You can use cookies,querystring,local storage , session storage etc for passing data from one page to another

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Can you mention that in your question with full code for gridview ?

Comment: Edited, thanks for looking into my post.

Comment: Where did you set value in `currentList`  for `gridview` ?

Comment: From your model `currentList ` can only for getting not for set value

Comment: Since this is a "prototype", In the second form, the gridview is only to be displayed, no changes will be made to it. The happens with my ddls, in the second page, I just want a clone ddl, no updates will be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Session :

In the first page:

```
Session["myddlstore"] = myFirstDDL.DataSource;
```

and in the second page

```
mySecondDDL.DataSource = Session["myddlstore"];
mySecondDDL.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE**

If the dropdowlinst items are added by the user, then you can implement something like this in the *button click* that adds item to the dropdownlist:

```
  List<string> myitems = new List<string> ();
  if(Session["myitems"] != null)
  {
      myitems = (List<string>) Session["myitems"];
  }

  myitems.Add(txt_NewItem.Text);

  myFirstDDL.DataSource = myitems;
  myFirstDDL.DataBind();
```

and, similarly. in the second page

```
 mySecondDDL.DataSource = Session["myitems"];
 mySecondDDL.DataBind();
 Session["myitems"] = myitems;
```

If you store a more complex object in dropdownlist, I would define a class that represents the complex object, and still use the approach  described above (`List<ObjectType>`).

Comment: In the first page, would "myFirstDDL.DataSource;" pass all items from the ddl to the session variable?
I am asking because in the first page, the ddl is fed from user input in a textbox.

Comment: Erkaner,  I declared the list out of the "button click" function. I see items being added to the first ddl, unfortunately those items are not loaded to the second ddl. I put a breakpoint in the second webform at "ddl_ingenieros.DataSource = Session["myItems"];" ... the session variable is losing its content somewhere.

Comment: @DMS ohh, we never stored the data in the session! just after this `txt_newAdmin.Text = "";` add this `Session["myItems"] = myItems;`

Comment: It worked! I see the second ddl populated now! Many many thanks Erkaner